# Why do you need to set the WORKON_HOME environment variable?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I haven't used my python/virtual environments in a while, but I do have virtualenvironment wrapper installed also.

My question is, in the doc page it says to do this:

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/Envs
$ mkdir -p $WORKON_HOME
$ source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
$ mkvirtualenv env1
```

I simply did this at my prompt:

```
source /usr/local/bin/virutalenvwrapper.sh
```

And now I can list and select an environment by doing:

```
>workon

>workon envtest1
```

My question is, since this works for me, I'm confused why I should be creating an environmental variable WORKON_HOME and point it to the ~/Envs folder?  What does that do and how come mine works fine w/o it?  I don't have that /Envs folder either (I know the script creates it).

Reference: http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 12):

If `WORKON_HOME` is not set, your default virtualenv folder will be set to `~/.virtualenvs`
(see [virtualenvwrapper.sh l.118](https://bitbucket.org/dhellmann/virtualenvwrapper/src/a766226010beb5df341bcb4bceb2befaba8603d4/virtualenvwrapper.sh?at=default#cl-118))

You will also use `WORKON_HOME` to specify to `pip` which folder to use (`export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=$WORKON_HOME`)

source : [virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org : Tying to pip’s virtualenv support](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tips.html#tying-to-pip-s-virtualenv-support)

Comment: `PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE` is deprecated: https://bitbucket.org/dhellmann/virtualenvwrapper/issue/225/pip_virtualenv_base-and

Comment: My home projects folder is `~/Projects`.  I stumbled across this answer because I was experiencing the same issue **and** I wasn't able to force it to recognize when I did have the `$WORKON_HOME` variable set.  Finally I just did a `ln -s ~/Projects ~/.virtualenvs`.  Problem solved.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: So that $WORKON_HOME is indeed optional if you are happy with putting those project envs in the default ~/.virtualenvs  and then the next question is, is there any motivation to use a different-than-default folder?

Comment: @RayLuo yeah it's optional if you're fine with `~/.virtualenvs`. I don't think there's any motivation other than personal preference. I know some IDEs (PyCharm I think? maybe Sublime?) are able to look into virtualenvs to improve autocompletion but you should be able to choose the path to the virtualenv for that kind of plugin so it doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm confused why I should be creating an environmental variable
>   WORKON_HOME and point it to the ~/Envs folder?

It's optional. You're confused (like I was) because the documentation is confusing.

> What does that do and how come mine works fine w/o it?

It tells `virtualenvwrapper` which folder to search for Python environments. The command `workon` searches the path `WORKON_HOME` if it's defined, or `~/.virtualenvs` if it's not, which is why it works by default.

A use case for defining a different `WORKON_HOME` directory would be if you have different environments you want to available to `virtualenvwrapper`. For example, if you save virtual env backups to a different folder or have multiple users who want to maintain their own environments.