# why virtualenv "workon' not work but activate can

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper

1.pip install virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper-win

2.mkvirtualenv newhouse

Then I want to go to the newhouse

3.workon newhouse

It not work.
I search for the solution and somehow I find a command and type it in the terminal and it works

```
PS C:\Users\huawei> & C:/Users/huawei/Envs/newhouse/Scripts/Activate.ps1

(newhouse) PS C:\Users\huawei>
```

Why is that? Why does the command `workon newhouse`not work?

Comment: What does it say when you use workon? Any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using it in powershell terminal in vscode try to create `command prompt terminal` in vscode and then you can able to use `**workon newhouse**` command.
Since `workon` is a batch script.
Try to run `workon` in cmd.
If you want to run it on powershell then i would recommend this stackoverflow question
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/38945456/14213012]