# virtualenvwrapper-win error: "No project directory found for current virtualenv"

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenvwrapper

What was done:

1. Created a folder on Google drive
2. copied my project files folder to the 1st folder
3. copied the virtual environment from my Envs folder to the 1st folder
4. put the folders from 2 & 3 in their respective locations on a new machine (I didn't want to use GitHub)
5. when trying to run `workon TDD` it activates the virtual environment then tells me:

> No project directory found for current virtualenv
>
> switches to the project dir of the activated virtualenv

If I run `setprojectdir "C:\Users\Kat\Documents\Programming\repo\TDD"` it tells me:

> The system cannot find the path specified.
>
> ```
> "C:\Users\Kat\Documents\Programming\repo\TDD" is now the project directory for
> virtualenv "C:\Users\OtherUsername\Envs\TDD" The system cannot find the path specified.
>
> "C:\Users\Kat\Documents\Programming\repo\TDD" added to
> C:\Users\OtherUsername\Envs\TDD\Lib\site-packages\virtualenv_path_extensions.pth
> ```
>
> ((TDD) ) C:\Users\Kat\Documents\Programming\repo\TDD>

But if I deactivate, move to a new folder, and activate again it acts as if no project folder was created.

What am I missing here? Do I just need to start over with the virtual environment? (This was just to test something, anyway.)

Comment: After some time away, I came back and realized the original computer this came from had a different username than mine (duh) ... So I checked the following:  (1) Confirmed my 2nd Envs folder had the TDD folder (it did but the script was looking for the wrong drive location - so nothing took) and then (2) found that the virtualenv_path_extensions.pth file (same location as original machine but on local) had the old project folder in it ..... will test and update soon

Comment: well that did nothing

Comment: back for another round found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47798786/10474024) that there was a file in my `C:\Users\USERFOLDER\Envs\PROJECT\Scripts` folder that the 1activate.bat` file was in there. I see reference to the old machine name so gonna fix those locations and see if that fixes it.

Comment: it worked!!! Well, with 1 small addition. But I'll post the answer soon.